# Android How to go back to Activity B, which contains an ID from A, from Activity C?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, android-actionbar

I have three activities. Activity A provides a list of groups. When you click on a group you proceed to Activity B, passing the Group ID of the clicked item, so that you could see details of that group. When you press an "Add" button on Activity B, you will proceed to Activity C.

Using the back and/or up button of the action bar, I could navigate from Activity B to Activity A without any problems. I could reload again the list items of Activity A. But when I press the back button of the action bar of Activity C to go to Activity B an error occurs because the passed group ID from Activity A is not recovered.

Please tell me what is the best thing to do. I'm a newbie.

PS: I understand that there is the hardware back button but according to the requirements a back button from the action bar is required.

Comment: First off, are you using NavUtils to navigate? And why do you kill Actvity B when navigating to Activity C?

Comment: you can use static variable and set id to that and use it in activities

Comment: You can use StartActivityForResult() function for starting Activity C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to kill activities when you navigate from Activity A to Activity B and then to Activity C. Most probably, you are killing the activities and this is the reason that reference to that groupId from Activity A is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are intenting from Activity C to B. By doing this, you have called the onCreate method of Activity B. So i will suggest you to code list this in your Activity C

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you press the back button in the action bar, are you creating the new intent and push the activity. if so then you have to pass the id to class.

if you call `finish()` instead of creating the intent in the onClick listener of the back button, I think there will be no issue in recovering the id.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file use meta-data tag like this, e.g,

```
         <activity ...>   

            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.org.abc.board" />

         </activity>
```